# Menu responsive JS, CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy trabajando en un menú responsive el cual cuando es presionado el boton del menú cambia la propiedad **overflow** del body a **hidden**, lo que busco hacer es que cuando se haga click en alguno de los links del menu la propiedad **overflow** de **body** cambie a **scroll** , espero puedan ayudarme, adjunto el código

[codigo html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGfzM.png) 
 [codigo js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0Slh.png)

```js
const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
const navLinks = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li");
const lock = document.querySelector(".body");




hamburger.addEventListener("click", () => {

    navLinks.classList.toggle("open");

    links.forEach(link =>{
        
        link.classList.toggle("fade");
        lock.classList.toggle("lock");
    }); 

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Podrías agregarles un eventListener a los links:

```
links.forEach(link =>{
  link.addEventListener("click", () => {
    navLinks.classList.toggle("open");
    link.classList.toggle("fade");
    lock.classList.toggle("lock");
  });
});
```

Visto que es tu primera pregunta en el sitio, te recomiendo visitar este enlace: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
y especialmente este: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar repetir código, necesitas crear una función que puedas ejecutar varias veces y asignarla a dos o más eventos. Luego, en el evento, asignas solo el nombre de esa función.

La idea es que el menú se cierre con clic en la "hamburguesa" y en cualquier elemento de la lista que contiene el menú. No importa si también escuchas clics en los enlaces (a menos que canceles el evento con `event.preventDefault()`) que, de ser el caso, también desde ahí puedes ejecutar la función.

Aprovechando que ya se tiene la función, también puedes cerrar el menú cuando se haga clic fuera de él.

```js
const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
const navLinks = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li");
// Modifiqué esta variable para poder probar
const lock = document.body;

// Crea una función para abrir o cerrar menú
function menuToggle() {
    console.log('Abrir o cerrar menú');
    navLinks.classList.toggle("open");
    links.forEach(link =>{
        link.classList.toggle("fade");
        lock.classList.toggle("lock");
    }); 
}

// En el evento asigna la función creada previamente
hamburger.addEventListener("click", menuToggle);
// También la lista va a ejecutarla en cada clic
navLinks.addEventListener("click", menuToggle);

links.forEach(link => {
    // No importa si escuchas clic también en los enlaces
    link.addEventListener('click', e => {
        console.log('Clic en enlace');
    });
});

// ¿Cerrar el menú cuando se haga clic fuera de él?
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
    // e.target es el elemento donde se hizo clic
    // Hay que asegurar que:
    // 1 - El menú está abierto
    // 2 - El clic no fue en la hamburguesa
    // 3 - El clic no fue en el menú
    // 4 - Tampoco fue en los enlaces del menú
    if(
        navLinks.classList.contains('open') // 1
        && e.target != hamburger            // 2
        && e.target != navLinks             // 3
        && !navLinks.contains(e.target)     // 4
    ) {
        console.log('Clic fuera del menú');
        // Cerrar menú
        menuToggle();
    }
});
```

```css
.lock { overflow: hidden; }
.nav-links { display: none; }
.nav-links.open { display: block; }
p { min-height: 120vh; }
```

```html
<span class="hamburger">☰</span>
<ul class="nav-links">
    <li><a href="#">Enlace 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Enlace 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Enlace 3</a></li>
</ul>
<p>Este es solo para agregar barra de desplazamiento.</p>
```